# Using jQuery to remove a class based on selectedIndex

Tags: jquery, selectedindex

Alright so I'm trying to remove a class based on a dropdown menu's selectedIndex, specifically, I want the div with the id=hide to appear when someone selects the second option in my dropdown menu (selectedIndex of 1), and disappear again if they select a different option.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="product-variants">      
                <select id="product-select" name="id">

                        <option value="269270508">No Charm</option>

                        <option value="269270608">Heart (Add $25)</option>

                        <option value="269270614">Horseshoe Bead (Add $25)</option>

                        <option value="269270666">Crystal Horseshoe (Add $25)</option>

                        <option value="269270692">Cowgirl Cross (Add $25)</option>

                        <option value="269270732">Lucky Charm (Add $35)</option>

                        <option value="270460652">Round (Add $25)</option>

                        <option value="269270562">Small Star (Add $20)</option>

                        <option value="269270598">Large Star (Add $25)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="hide" class="hidden"><form>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Engraving?<br>
</form>
    <form>
Engraving Message: <input type="text" name="engraving"><br>
        </form></div>
```

My script:

```
var choice = getElementById("product-select").selectedIndex;

if (choice == 1){

    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        $('#hide').removeClass('hidden');
    });

}
```

And CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display:none
}
```

And a link to it on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AFrjz/2/

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and just can't seem to do it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (choice == 1){

  //$('#checkbox').change(function(){ you are callinjg a change event here... so the hide is not fired..
    $('#hide').removeClass('hidden');
 // });

}
```

**UPDATED**

> I want the div with the id=hide to appear when someone selects the second option in my dropdown menu (selectedIndex of 1), and disappear again if they select a different option.

i used the change event of the selectbox.. and checked the selected value.. if value is your second options's value.. then remove class else addclass

```
$("#product-select").change(function(){
 var choice = $(this).val()

 if (choice == '269270608'){

//$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#hide').removeClass('hidden');  //remove class here
//});

 }else{
    $('#hide').removeClass().addClass('hidden');  //else addclass
 }

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/AFrjz/5/)

Comment: Worked great outside of Shopify, but can't get it to work inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all in jQuery way like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AFrjz/6/

```
$('#product-select').change(function () {
   var choice = $("#product-select option:selected").index();
   if (choice == 1) {
       $('#hide').removeClass('hidden');
   } else {
       $('#hide').addClass('hidden');
   }
});
```

You have to grab the selected index on change of the `<select>` then compare it in `if`.

There is no need to call the change function on `checkbox` to hide or show itself.

Comment: Awesome, that worked when I tried it.  Except here is the new problem: I am trying to utilize this in a Shopify store and it isn't working for some reason, not sure if you have any experience there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following correction.

- You have document. before getElementById. Change `getElementById` to 
  `document.getElementById`
- You binded the change event with hidden checkbox so you wont be able
  to trigger event show checkbox to select it.
- Add condition in event handler instead of binding event in condition.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFrjz/4/)**

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){    
   var choice = document.getElementById("product-select").selectedIndex;
    alert(choice)
   if (choice == 1){
     $('#hide').removeClass('hidden');
   }
});
```

**To see the effect of `removeClass` select the second item in the select and select the check box.**

Comment: Tried this one too, worked perfectly when I tried it, but no luck inside Shopify.